# tqdm loading bar bug

Tags: python, loading, tqdm

the beginning of my loop looks like this -

`for fname in tqdm(range(len(images)), position = 0, leave = True):`

```
  0%|          | 0/26 [00:00<?, ?it/s]26 images found.
100%|██████████| 26/26 [00:13<00:00,  1.86it/s]
```

Any idea why this might be happening? (I need it to only print once)

I fixed it but I don't understand why it works.
I have a print statement before my loop, if I remove it - it works fine, but it doesn't without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a print statement inside your `for loop` it will print to your terminal and then display back the loading bar, so you will see multiple loading bar.

Comment: Didn't fix it :(

Comment: What is your issue exactly ?

Comment: It shouldn't be printing twice?

Comment: Don't you have a print statement, or an exception that might be print inside your for loop ?

Comment: not sure i understand what you mean, but i dont have a print statement inside the loop

Comment: Otherwise I know that resizing the windows where it is printed while execution might provok this issue

Comment: I found the error, I was having a print statement before the loop. If i commented it, it works fine now but with it it doesnt work. so i dont understand this behaviour exactly

Comment: Having a print statement just before the loop shouldn't be an issue, If I add print("something") before the for loop i don't manage to reproduce the issue you describe